# Having some issues in InventoryController class?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

These days i am learning spring by http://static.springsource.org.
I am facing some problem in this page http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html. i am not getting it clearly that when setProductManager method is called when  InventoryController class is invoked. I know that this works as a front controller and when hello.jsp page is requested ,ModelAndView  method is executed of InventoryController. but i want to know that when setProductManager method is called.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is an [ioc](/questions/tagged/ioc) container and in this particular example the [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) is implemented using setters (*setter injection*). Basically the container takes care of supplying your bean (controller in this case) with necessary dependencies.

Back to your question: dependency injection is performed before your bean is ever used by the framework or any other beans requiring it. Furthermore, controllers are singletons. This means `setProductManager` is called before any request is handled by the controller - when the application is started. And because there is only one instance of the controller - it is called once.

Comment: Which are the most important topics of spring for web development?

Comment: @NaveenChauhan : ioc container and dependency injection are given in answer by Tomasz. Also You can read these topics http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html